# QProcess cannot read from a async Function of telethon

Tags: python, asynchronous, pyqt5, qprocess, telethon

I am running a python file from a QProcess in a PyQt5 GUI.
I am showing everything from the terminal using readAllStandardOutput(I tried readAll also) to a textBox
In the python file, I am using telethon (library for using telegram API) python file is having a async event-handler in which I am printing something.
But before starting the starting the client readAllStandardOutput is reading fine. BUt after that print("Sent Hi!") is neither showing on the terminal nor Qprocess is reading it.
Pyqt5 GUI file having QProcess declaration.

```
class MainWindow(QMainWindow):
def __init__(self,parent = None):
    super(QMainWindow, self).__init__(parent)
    self.process = QProcess(self)
    self.process.readyReadStandardOutput.connect(self.stdoutReady)
    self.process.readyReadStandardError.connect(self.stderrReady)
    self.process.started.connect(lambda: print('Started!'))
    self.process.finished.connect(lambda: print('Finished!'))
    self.process.setProcessChannelMode(QProcess.MergedChannels)

    def startMain(self):
        self.process.start('python3', ['mainApp2.py'])

    def stdoutReady(self):
        text = str(self.process.readAllStandardOutput())
        self.mainTextBox.setText(str(text.strip()))
```

The python file QProess will start

```
import asyncio
loop = asyncio.new_event_loop()
asyncio.set_event_loop(loop)
print("Main App started")
api_id = #api_id integer
api_hash = "api_hash string"
client = TelegramClient('session', api_id, api_hash , loop = loop )
async def say_after(delay, what):
    await asyncio.sleep(delay)
    print(what)
@client.on(events.NewMessage)
async def my_event_handler(event):
    if 'hello' in event.raw_text:
        await event.reply('Hi!')
        await say_after(1, 'Sent Hi!')
        
client.start()
client.run_until_disconnected()
```

"Main app Started" is displayed on the text box but not "Sent Hi!".
And the event.reply('Hi!') is working fine.
I am not sure may be it is because it is creating a child process

I want to redirect all output from the terminal to the textBox in the GUI (if you have other methods do suggest).

Comment: post your code so people can help you

Comment: @TheKill-996 Added